# Which symbols should be escaped with a backslash in php regex?

Tags: php, regex, escaping

```
preg_match('@\.php@',$url,$match)
```

Common:-

- slash
- quotation
- double quotation

any others?

Should `@`, `?`, `=` be escaped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a list of special Regex characters in the PHP documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

> The special regular expression characters are: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you will find the [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) function useful:

> preg_quote() takes str and puts a backslash in front of every
>   character that is part of the regular expression syntax. This is
>   useful if you have a run-time string that you need to match in some
>   text and the string may contain special regex characters.
>
> The special regular expression characters are: . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) {
>   } = ! < > | : -

Answer (score 2):

`@` and `?` should be backslashified, `=` should not.

The characters you need to backslash escape in a regex include:

- Square brackets `[]`
- Parentheses `()`
- Curly braces `{}`
- Caret `^`
- Dollar sign `$`
- Period `.`
- Pipe `|`
- Asterisk `*`
- Plus `+`
- Question mark `?`
- Backslashes `\`

Additionally, your regex delimiter, in this case `@`, needs to be backslashified.

It is important to note that certain characters may be metacharacters in a certain context. For example, the hyphen is not a metacharacter in the regex denoted by this string:

```
"/foo-/"
```

But *is* a metacharacter in the following string:

```
"/foo[a-z]/"
```